# how to select first checkbox with array and select any one sibling using jquery

Tags: jquery

If i have checked list 0  and i am going to check any one from the sibling either list 1 nor list 2 . I have tried with at least check one from the list.

```
    <div><input name="list[]" id="list0" type="checkbox"  value="newsletter0" >zero</div>
    <div><input name="list[]" id="list1" type="checkbox"  value="newsletter1" >one</div>
    <div><input name="list[]" id="list2" type="checkbox"  value="newsletter2" >two</div>
```

Comment: Post your tried code.

Comment: Your checkboxes aren't siblings. The div's they are in are siblings, which would make the checkboxes "cousins" (children of siblings)

Comment: i need this if i have checked list 0 and i am going to check any one from the list  either list 1 nor list 2

Comment: what you want to do is not clear for me? are you want to check any one at a time. ? if no , could you please explain what you want ?

Comment: i am using named array checkbox , if i have checked the id=list0 means i have able to check either list 1 id or list2 not both is checked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully I am understanding your question correctly: If the user checks zero, you want them to be able to check one OR two, but NOT both one AND two?

See this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/3ABJC/). Hopefully it will suit your needs or at least show you how to achieve what you want:

http://jsfiddle.net/3ABJC/

```
$('#list0,#list1,#list2').change(function() {
    if ($('#list0').is(':checked')) {
        // if either one of list1 or list2 is checked
        if ($('#list1:checked,#list2:checked').length == 1) {
            // disable the one that is not checked
            $('#list1:not(:checked),#list2:not(:checked)').prop('disabled',true);
        } else {
            // neither are checked, make sure they are all enabled
            $('#list1,#list2').prop('disabled', false);
        }
    } else {
        // if both are one and two are checked
        if ($('#list1:checked,#list2:checked').length == 2) {
            // disable zero (so you can't have all 3 checked)
            $('#list0').prop('disabled', true);
        } else {
            // otherwise, make sure all are enabled
            $('#list0,#list1,#list2').prop('disabled', false);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: i need to display error message,if  the checkbox (list 1 and 2) is not checked

Comment: `if ($('#list0:checked,#list1:not(:checked),#list2:not(:checked)').length == 3) alert('You must also select list1 or list2');`

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution http://jsfiddle.net/7zQtE/

HTML

```
    <div><input name="list[]" id="list0" type="checkbox" value="newsletter0" />zero</div>
    <div><input name="list[]" id="list1" type="checkbox" value="newsletter1" disabled="disabled" />one</div>
    <div><input name="list[]" id="list2" type="checkbox" value="newsletter2" disabled="disabled" />two</div>
    <!-- Added button -->
    <input type="button" id="btn" value="Check" />
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#list0').on('change', function(){
        $(this).prop('checked') ? $('#list1,#list2').removeAttr('disabled') : $('#list1,#list2').attr('disabled', 'disabled').removeAttr('checked');
    });

    $('#list1,#list2').on('change', function(){
        $(this).prop('checked') ? $('input[name=list\\[\\]]:not(:checked)').attr('disabled', 'disabled') : $('input[name=list\\[\\]]:not(:checked)').removeAttr('disabled');
    });

    //Added button handler
    $('#btn').on('click', function(){
        if($('#list0').prop('checked') && !$('#list1,#list2').prop('checked')){
            alert('check item 1 or 2');
        }    
    })
});
```

Comment: how to display error message (please select one from the following)

Comment: if i click the submit button to validate the check box and if list 1 or list 2  not checked means display the error message. please reply me

Comment: see update, if list0 checked -> check is list1 or list2 has checked property